# Overlap in between 2 JQuery Click Function

Tags: jquery

```
<input id="btnPost" type="button" value="Post" style="width: 79px" />
<input id="btnAssign" type="button" value="Assign" style="width: 79px" />
<div id="div1">
    <textarea rows="10" cols="2" style="width: 401px"></textarea><br />
    <input id="btnPost2" type="submit" name="btnPost" value="Post" style="width: 60px" />
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <textarea rows="10" cols="2" style="width: 401px"></textarea><br />
    <input id="btnAssign2" type="submit" name="btnAssign" value="Assign" style="width: 60px" />    
</div>
```

## JavaScript :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#div1').hide();            

        $('#btnPost').click(function () {
            $('#div1').toggle('fast');                
        });                           
});

$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#div2').hide();           

        $('#btnAssign').click(function () {               
            $('#div2').toggle('fast');               
        });                            
});
```

### My query is as follows:

When I am clicking "Post" button, "#div1" is appearing. But when I am clicking "Assign" button without minimizing "div1" then both "#div1" and "#div2" are displaying at the same time.

I tried in www.jsFiddle.com
for more detail follow this link : http://jsfiddle.net/RfgkU/69/

Comment: I guess what he wants is for one of them to appear at all times, but his jquery works fine, just need to hide the other one when clicking on one of them

Comment: @Huangism: Yes you are right. I just needed to hide the other one when clicking on one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only one of the divs to be visible at the time, you can try this for your JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#div1, #div2').hide();            

        $('#btnPost').click(function () {
            $('#div1').toggle('fast');
            $('#div2').hide();
        });                                                  

        $('#btnAssign').click(function () {               
            $('#div2').toggle('fast');
            $('#div1').hide();
        });                            
});
```

As you can see on [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/RfgkU/72/)